# Compute a measure of "near multiplicity" from a list of noisy values

Tags: statistics

## Question

I posted [this question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48791712/190597) before but someone advised me to ask it there because it looks like a numerical algorithm problem.

Let us say I've got a list of values which have a common multiple greater than 1. For example, let us take the multiple to be 3 and form a collection of multiples of this value:

```
harmonicList = [3,6,6,3,3,9,27,3,15,18,9]
```

Now I add some noise:

```
harmonicList = [ v + (random() * 2 - 1 ) * 0.1 for v in harmonicList]
```

I'm searching for an algorithm that will return a number near 1.0 when the items in the list are near to being multiples of a common value but near 0.0 when the numbers are not near to being multiples -- such as, for example when the list is a collection of prime numbers.

Is there such a measure of "near multiplicity"?

## Why I want to solve this problem

I'm currently trying to detect Chessboard in a screenshot using Hough Transform. Sometimes the case is ideal, and it works very well :
[image]

But sometimes not :
[image]

I would like to detect the cases where there is a lot of aberrations. Thus, my idea is to compute the intersections of the lines detected, and create a collection of length  (only if the lines where horizontal or vertical). If the detection was good, I know that there will be a great "harmonicity" inside this collection I can then use that algorithm and a threshold.

Comment: Is this something principle component analysis is intended to solve? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis

Comment: I've no idea but will have a look

Comment: EDIT: I've moved my comment to an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at this as a maximum likelihood estimation problem. The general idea is to find parameters which make the model fit the data in the sense that the data have greatest probability under the model for the specified parameters. Maximum likelihood is a very widely used approach for fitting statistical models.

In this case, your model is p(x) = sum of p_1(x, mean = k times a minus b, standard deviation = something small) over k from 1 to number of multiples, where a is the spacing between multiples and b is an offset, and p_1 is the Gaussian density exp(minus 1/2 times ((x minus mean)/(s.d.)) squared)/(s.d. times sqrt(2 pi)).

Compute log likelihood, i.e. log(p(x_1) times p(x_2) ... times p(x_n)) = log(p(x_1)) + ... + log(p(x_n)) where n = number of data which is typically easier to handle numerically than the equivalent likelihood. Note log likelihood is a function of a and b, so maximize log likelihood over a and b to find the "best" values.

EDIT: Here's an implementation of the formulas above. I'm using Maxima, a computer algebra system for this. See: http://maxima.sourceforge.net

Here is the Maxima program:

```
p_1(x, mean, sd) := exp(-(1/2)*((x - mean)/sd)^2)/(sd*sqrt(2*%pi));

p(x) := sum (p_1(x, k*a + b, sd), k, 0, k_max);

log_likelihood(xx, a, b) := lsum (log (p(xx1)), xx1, xx);
```

Here are the data for the example stated in the question:

```
harmonicList : [3,6,6,3,3,9,27,3,15,18,9];

harmonicList : map (lambda ([v], v + (random(1.0) * 2 - 1 ) * 0.1), harmonicList);
```

These are some additional parameters. `k_max` is the maximum number of multiples to look at; that can probably be estimated by looking at the range of the data. `sd` is the standard deviation of the noise. It should probably be stated as a fraction of `a`, the distance between multiples.

```
k_max : 10;
sd : 0.2;
```

Here is a contour plot of the log likelihood, given `harmonicList` as the data.

```
contour_plot (lambda ([a, b], log_likelihood (harmonicList, a, b)),
              [a, 1, 5], [b, 0, 3],
              [gnuplot_preamble, "set cntrparam levels 12"],
              [grid, 120, 120]);
```

Here is the resulting contour plot:

[image: Contours of log likelihood over a and b]

Note that the greatest values (a little above zero) are in the vicinity of (a = 3, b = 0) and (a = 3, b = 3).

EDIT 2: Here is my response to the question about answering the question of whether the data could be fit by any multiplier.

You could approach that question like this. The plausibility of "data can be fit by some multiplier, offset pair" can be modeled as p(model | data) which is

p(model | data) = p(data | model) p(model) / (p(data | model) p(model) + p(data | no model) p(no model))

This shows what terms one needs to pull together to get a complete answer, namely p(data | model), p(model), p(data | no model), and p(no model).

About p(model) and p(no model), since it's possible that there is no such multiplier and offset, we have p(model) < 1. This might be estimated as the base rate of data sets which can be modeled by multiplier and offset. About p(data | no model), this is probably something like a uniform distribution.

As for p(data | model), note that p(data | model) = p(data, model) / p(model). Now p(data, model) =  integral(p(data | a', b') p(a', b' | model) over all conceivable values a', b' of multiplier a and offset b). Note that p(data | a', b') is, by definition, the likelihood of model = (a', b') given the data. Remember that likelihood = exp(log likelihood).

Here p(a', b' | model) is one's prior over the parameter values, assuming that the data are accounted for by some multiplier, offset pair. Are all parameters equally probable a priori? If so p(a', b' | model) is a constant. My guess is that some values are more probably than others due to the constraints of the problem -- since the images are screenshots, there are probably limits on what the multiplier and offset can be, and probably some values are less probable given those limits.

EDIT 3: Here is the contour plot for `primeList` as given in a comment below.

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to turn the log likelihoods into a single number which is a measure of how likely the data came from multiples of an underlying value?

Comment: I've updated my answer to talk about an answer to that question.

Comment: What will happens if instead I use a  sequence where there is a poor multiplicity ? like primeList : [2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23];
primeList : map (lambda ([v], v + (random(1.0) * 2 - 1 ) * 0.1), primeList); how is the countour plot ? I could try it myself but I can't download maxima today, I get the following message when trying to access their page : "Project web is currently offline pending the final migration of its data to our new datacenter."

Comment: @snoobdogg: I posted a Python implementation of Robert Dodier's idea [on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48833918/190597) since it is only about implementation, not theory.

Comment: @snoobdogg I've pasted in a contour plot for primeList. Note that the greatest values are something like -100 instead of 0. That means that the multiples model is a very poor fit for the primeList data compared to the harmonicList. About Maxima, the project hosting site (Sourceforge) is updating their data center but hopefully that will be resolved soon.